# Displaying array of mouse event when draw in drawing apps - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html5-canvas

I was trying to get the array coordinates of mouse in canvas, but when i try it won't show the line/drawing. is there anyway to get the array to display them?

```js
       

var drawMouse = function() {
 var clicked = 0;

 
 var start = function(e) {
  var pointX = [];
  var pointY = [];
  clicked = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY-44;
  ctx.moveTo(x,y);
 };
 var move = function(e) {
  if(clicked){
   x = e.pageX;
   y = e.pageY-44;
   ctx.lineTo(x,y);
   ctx.stroke();
   pointX.push(x);
   pointY.push(y);
   
  } 
 };
 
 var stop = function(e) {
  clicked = 0;
  
  var coords = document.getElementById("coords");
  for (var i = 0; l = pointX.lenght; i<l; i++){
  coords.innerHTML += pointX[i]+ "-" + pointY[i]+ "<br/>";
  }
 };

    document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
 document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
 document.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
};
```

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < pointX.length; i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var clicked = 0;
var pointX = [];
var pointY = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var start = function(e) {
  clicked = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
};
var move = function(e) {
  if (clicked) {
    x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
    pointX.push(x);
    pointY.push(y);

  }
};

var stop = function(e) {
  clicked = 0;
  var coords = document.getElementById("coords");
  for (var i = 0, l = pointX.length; i < l; i++) {
    coords.innerHTML += pointX[i] + "-" + pointY[i] + "<br/>";
  }
};

document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
```

```css
canvas{
 border : 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width=300 height=300></canvas>
<p id='coords'></p>
```

You have typo `for (var i = 0; l = pointX.lenght; i<l; i++)` , you need to change to `for (var i = 0, l = pointX.length; i<l; i++)` and mouse pointer offset which is used to draw in canvas.